# Why Spark Streaming No Receiver approach is still experimental?

Tags: spark-streaming

No Receiver(Direct) approach in Spark Streaming + Kafka is still experimental[Spark 2.0 Version] or I can use it in Production Systems?

Comment: Good question, I think it just went about unnoticed. We're currently using it in production, definitely not in the experimental phase anymore.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov : Thanks Yuval, good to know that you are using it in Production.

Comment: From mail archive, it looks like they just didn't get time to update the docs..! https://www.mail-archive.com/user%40spark.apache.org/msg53738.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although "No Receiver approach in Spark Streaming + Kafka" is still in experimental (officially based on the Spark Docs), I believe it is safe to use in Production Systems (It was first introduced in Spark 1.3 for Scala/Java & 1.4 for Python).
The feature was introduced long back. I know people who are using this in Production Environment.